# How do I prevent PySide signals and slots from trying to convert binary string data to Unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, signals-slots

PySide signals and slots seem to be silently converting my binary strings to unicode. How can I avoid it? Alternatively, how can I pass along binary data via the signals-slots interface without PySide mutating it?

```
from PySide import QtCore

class Thingy(QtCore.QObject):
    data = QtCore.Signal(str)

@QtCore.Slot(str)
def printdata(x):
    print "type=%s, x=%s" % (type(x), x.__repr__())

thingy = Thingy()
thingy.data.connect(printdata)

for data in ('Hey', '\x55\xaa'):
    printdata(data)
    thingy.data.emit(data)
```

This prints out:

```
type=<type 'str'>, x='Hey'
type=<type 'unicode'>, x=u'Hey'
type=<type 'str'>, x='U\xaa'
type=<type 'unicode'>, x=u'U\xaa'
```

Comment: What's the point of the '\x55\xaa' case?

Comment: Because it's binary data. 55AA is a common test case (and one that caused parts of my code to bomb).

Comment: Is there something I can do to clarify my answer or help make it more applicable?

Answer (score 4):

You can just replace the type specifier in the signal and the slot by `object` and PySide will not invoke any conversions.

```
from PySide import QtCore

class Thingy(QtCore.QObject):
    data = QtCore.Signal(object)

@QtCore.Slot(object)
def printdata(x):
    print "type=%s, x=%s" % (type(x), x.__repr__())

thingy = Thingy()
thingy.data.connect(printdata)

for data in ('Hey', '\x55\xaa'):
    printdata(data)
    thingy.data.emit(data)
```

gives

```
type=<type 'str'>, x='Hey'
type=<type 'str'>, x='Hey'
type=<type 'str'>, x='U\xaa'
type=<type 'str'>, x='U\xaa'
```

This allows you to send binary data.

Comment: Did you actually try this?

Comment: @DanialSank I didn't just guess the indicated output.

Comment: I was confused by "(at least I hope so)" in your answer.

Comment: @DanialSank Oh you're right, that might sound strange. The problem is that I don't know enough about the inner workings of the PySide bindings and the C++ part of Qt. I imagine that in principle they only need to hand a general reference around and the type specification is just for additional type safety, but if you chose str than there is a conversion, so that might not be right. So I tested that this works, I only do not know why it works.

Comment: Got it. Your answer is better than mine, I think. OP should accept it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing for python 2. In python 3 this situation is probably more sensible (but I don't know for sure).

Within Qt, the string class is `QString`. When pyside wants to pass a QString *into python*, it chooses the `unicode` type. This is a Good Thing, because QString supports unicode. There is no way to tell the Qt libs that the QString is actually supposed to be a byte array, so once your python `str` is converted to QString, you're going to get a unicode back. From this you see that the problem really happens when you pass your str *into Qt* and pyside converts the python str to QString.

Why does pyside convert python str to QString instead of eg. `QByteArray`? In python 2 there isn't a separate type for byte arrays, so str does double duty as a byte array and as text. My guess is that QString is the default because str *usually* represents text.

If you had ASCII text, the simplest solution would be to just call `str()` at the beginning of your slot:

```
@QtCore.Slot(str)
def printdata(x):
    x = str(x)
    print "type=%s, x=%s" % (type(x), x.__repr__())
```

However, as you said in the question, you have binary data, so this won't work. One solution is to tell the signal to accept your own custom type:

```
class Thingy(QtCore.QObject):
    data = pyqtSignal(<your custom byte array type>)
```

You can then make your own byte array type which uses str under the hood (make sure it's a new style class).

Finally, you could just use QByteArray:

```
class Thingy(QtCore.QObject):
    data = pyqtSignal(QByteArray)
```

Comment: I really have binary data (thought I was clear about that in my question).

Comment: "The simplest solution is to just call str() at the beginning of your slot:" -- Nope, because then I run into some crazy Unicode / ASCII issues. I was able to workaround by wrapping my type in a Python class.

Comment: I'll use QByteArray, now that I know about it. :-)

Comment: @JasonS: Yes, if you have binary, QByteArray is a good bet. My apologies for not understanding that you were dealing with binary strings. I've edited the question with this in mind.